# How do I invoke the OnReceive() function when a set alarm goes off?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I have been trying all day to invoke the BroadcastReceiver.OnReceive() function on the Android. I am using Android AIDE for my projects, but nothing seems to work. I am using...

```
        Intent openNewAlarm = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
        startActivity(openNewAlarm);
```

to set my alarm, and a dialog comes up that allows me to set as many alarms as I would like, but instead of a ringtone, I would like to program (through an OnReceive() function) what I would like to happen instead. What can I do to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   Intent startIntent = new Intent("BROADCAST");
    PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, startPIntent);
```

And then in your Manifest.xml file:

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.YourOnReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="BROADCAST" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I did. I still can't get the onReceive function to work. triggerTime was also undefined, but I assume it is the time in milliseconds. How would I get whatever information I enter into the dialog, and convert it into the milliseconds I need to store in the triggerTime variable? When I entered the code above, the dialog doesn't show up anymore. I also have...

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>